# Sharepoint client api. Call custom function

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, client, sharepoint-api

Can i call custom created function from sharepoint client api?

I need to call function on server:

```
public class ClientCallsReciever
{
   public void CustomFunction()
   {
      //A LOT OF CODE ON SERVER
   }
}
```

So is it possible to do on client something like:

```
Context.Completed+=CompletedHandler;

Context.Invoke("CustomFunction");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly call a method on the server from the client. You'd need to create a Web service and expose the method through it.

Comment: Just thought that we have more easy way)